# How to change Git version in RStudio on Mac OS 11 (M1)

Tags: git, macos, installation, rstudio, homebrew

I have two versions of Git installed on my computer (which runs Mac OS 11 on an M1 chip). `git version 2.37.0 (Apple Git-136)` came pre-installed. Unfortunately, I found that version to cause some issues and decided to switch to the regular version. I used Home Brew to install `git version 2.42.0` from the regular Mac OS terminal and `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` to change to using this new Git version.

In order to test the installation, I ran `git --version` and `which git` in the Mac OS terminal, VSCode's integrated terminal and RStudio's integrated terminal.

Using the Mac OS terminal as well as VSCode's terminal I get `git version 2.42.0` and `/opt/homebrew/bin/git`.

Using RStudio's terminal, however, I still get `git version 2.37.0 (Apple Git-136)` and `/usr/bin/git`.

I tried setting the Git executable in the global options to `/opt/homebrew/bin/git` in order to change to the same version VSCode and my Mac Terminal uses. However, when I do that, it refuses to accept it and changes to `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/git/2.42.0/bin/git`. Checking the version still results in `git version 2.37.0 (Apple Git-136)` then.

How can I change the regular Git version in RStudio?